# Open Google Maps InfoWindow based on certain criteria

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow, conditional-statements

I want to open a Google Maps `InfoWindow` based on whether or not one of my buildings is throwing a building alarm. The buildings I have the markers on all have alarm states (on or off), and if they are in alarm state, I am changing the color of the marker to yellow or red, depending on the severity of the alarm. When the alarms are "red" alarms, the marker is animated with the `google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE` effect.

The bounce effect is sometimes not enough to garner attention (we leave this screen open on a wall, and the data in the `$(this).children(".alarm-count")` div below changes dynamically due to another script we have running on the site in the background.

I already know how to change the markers based on the alarm state, can I also open an InfoWindow within the same condition? I have tried this:

```
        google.maps.event.addListener(map,'idle',(function(marker,i){
            return function(){
                infowindow.setContent(

                    '<div class="infowindow-inner">'+
                        '<a href="'+bldgGfx[i]+'" onclick="window.open('+bldgGfx[i]+');return false;" target="_blank" title="'+bldgName[i]+' ('+bldgAddr[i]+')">'+
                            '<h2>'+bldgName[i]+'</h2>'+
                            '<h4>'+bldgAddr[i]+'</h4>'+
                            '<p>'+mainMeter[i]+' kW</p>'+
                            '<p>'+alarmCount[i]+' Alarms</p>'+
                    '</div>'

                );infowindow.open(map,marker);
            }
        })(marker,i));
```

but it doesn't seem to be working.

**The long and short of it is I need to evaluate one value per marker in my page, and open (or not open) the InfoWindow for each building based on that value.**

Here is my code:

```
$(".building").each(function(i){

    bldgNo[i] = $(this).children(".bldg-no").html().slice(1);
    bldgName[i] =   $(this).children(".bldg-name").html();
    bldgAddr[i] =   $(this).children(".bldg-address").html();
    bldgGfx[i] =    $(this).children(".bldg-graphic").html();
    mainMeter[i] =  $(this).children(".main-meter").html();
    alarmCount[i] = $(this).children(".alarm-count").html();
    latitude[i] =   $(this).children(".latitude").html();
    longitude[i] =  $(this).children(".longitude").html();

    if (alarmCount[i]!="N/A"){alarmCount[i]=alarmCount[i].slice(0,-3);}
    if (alarmCount[i]>"0" && alarmCount[i]!="N/A"){
        marker=new google.maps.Marker({position:new google.maps.LatLng(latitude[i],longitude[i]),map:map,shadow:shadow,icon:redIcon,title:bldgName[i]+" \n"+bldgAddr[i],optimized:false});marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);


    ////    
    //// THE COMMAND TO OPEN THE INFOWINDOW WILL GO HERE, RIGHT?
    ////


    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass("new")||(mainMeter[i]=="N/A")||(!isNumber(mainMeter[i]))) {
        marker=new google.maps.Marker({position:new google.maps.LatLng(latitude[i],longitude[i]),map:map,shadow:shadow,icon:yellowIcon,title:bldgName[i]+" \n"+bldgAddr[i],optimized:false});marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.NULL);}
    else {
        marker=new google.maps.Marker({position:new google.maps.LatLng(latitude[i],longitude[i]),map:map,shadow:shadow,icon:greenIcon,title:bldgName[i]+" \n"+bldgAddr[i],optimized:false});marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.NULL);}

    markersArray.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',(function(marker,i){
        return function(){
            infowindow.setContent(

                '<div class="infowindow-inner">'+
                    '<a href="'+bldgGfx[i]+'" onclick="window.open('+bldgGfx[i]+');return false;" target="_blank" title="'+bldgName[i]+' ('+bldgAddr[i]+')">'+
                        '<h2>'+bldgName[i]+'</h2>'+
                        '<h4>'+bldgAddr[i]+'</h4>'+
                        '<p>'+mainMeter[i]+' kW</p>'+
                        '<p>'+alarmCount[i]+' Alarms</p>'+
                '</div>'

            );infowindow.open(map,marker);
        }
    })(marker,i));

    i++;

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since many buildings may be "on alert", you'll want a InfoWindow array (in my demo it's a global because I use an inline call); however, the screen may get cluttered very easily. I wrote a Z-Index routine to bring a clicked InfoWindow to front. You might also want to consider `MarkerWithLabel` or `InfoBubble` because in my opinion they look better than the vanilla InfoWindow.

Please [**see the demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/174/embedded/result/)

[*demo side-by-side with code*](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/174/)

I'll only copy some of the parts that are very different.

```
var infowindows = [];

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

  // MANY LINES SKIPPED
  // ...

  $(this).children(".longitude").html();

  infowindows[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content:'<div class="infowindow"
         onclick="bringToFront('+i+')">'+bldgName[i]+'</div>'});

  if (alarmCount[i]>0 && alarmCount[i]!="N/A"){
  //      marker=new google.maps.Marker({position:new google.maps.LatLng(latitude[i],longitude[i]),map:map,shadow:shadow,icon:redIcon,title:bldgName[i]+" \n"+bldgAddr[i],optimized:false});marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:new google.maps.LatLng(latitude[i],longitude[i]),map:map,title:"red"});

    infowindows[i].open(map,marker);

  //// THE COMMAND TO OPEN THE INFOWINDOW WILL GO HERE, RIGHT?
}

...

google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',(function(marker,i){
      return function(){
        infowindows[i].open(map,marker);
        bringToFront(i);
      }
    })(marker,i));
  });
}

function bringToFront(windowIndex) {
  console.log(windowIndex);
  for (var i = infowindows.length-1, n = 0; i >= n; i--) {
    infowindows[i].setZIndex(0);
  }
  infowindows[windowIndex].setZIndex(1);
}
```

Comment: Excellent! This worked perfectly! Thanks so much, Heitor.

Sorry for the delay; other things came up and I didn't get to this project until today. Your code was very helpful and actually helped me understand the ins and outs of Google maps better than before.

Have a great day!